# What is the scope of Postgres policies?

Tags: postgresql, policies

I am trying to wrap my head around row level security in Postgres. Unfortunately the documentation is not very verbose on the matter. My problem is the following:

I have two tables: `locations` and `locations_owners`. There is a `TRIGGER` set on `INSERT` for locations, which will automatically add a new row to the `locations_owners` table including the `request.jwt.claim.sub` [variable](http://postgrest.org/en/v6.0/api.html#accessing-request-headers-cookies-and-jwt-claims).

This works all just fine, however when I want to create a policy for `DELETE` like this:

```
CREATE POLICY location_delete ON eventzimmer.locations FOR DELETE TO organizer USING(
    (SELECT EXISTS (SELECT name FROM protected.locations_owners AS owners WHERE owners.name = name AND owners.sub = (SELECT current_setting('request.jwt.claim.sub', true))))
);
```

It will always evaluate to true, no matter the actual content. I know that I can call a custom procedure with `SELECT` here, however I ended up with the following questions:

- what is the scope of a `policy`? Can I access tables? Can I access procedures? The documentation says *"Any SQL conditional expression"* so `SELECT EXISTS` should be fine
- how are the column names of the rows mapped to the policy. The examples just magically use the column names (which I adopted by using the `name` variable), however I have not found **any** documentation about what this actually does
- what is the magic `user_name` variable. Where does it come from? I believe it is the current `role` which is executing the query, but how can I know?
- why is there no `WITH CHECK` expression available for `DELETE`? If I understand correctly, `WITH CHECK` will `fail` any row with invalid constraint, which is the behaviour I would prefer (because otherwise PostgREST will always return `204`)

I am a little bit confused by the astonishingly missing amount of information in the (otherwise) very good documentation of PostgreSQL. Where is this information? How can I find it?

For the sake of completeness I have also attached the column definitions below:

```
CREATE TABLE eventzimmer.locations (
  name varchar PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  latitude float NOT NULL,
  longitude float NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS protected.locations_owners (
    name varchar NOT NULL REFERENCES eventzimmer.locations(name) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    sub varchar NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: I had a similar issue in a function recently, and am quite certain you'll need to use `owners.name = locations.name` otherwise `name = name` always comes up as `TRUE`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Many of the questions will become clear once you understand how row level security is implemented: the conditions in the policies will automatically be added to the query, just as if you added another `WHERE` condition.

Use `EXPLAIN` to see the query plan, and you will see the policy's conditions in there.

- So you can use any columns from the table on which the policy is defined.

  Essentially, you can use anything in a policy definition that you could use in a `WHERE` conditions: Function calls, subqueries and so on.

  You can also qualify the column name with the table name if that is required for disambiguation. This can be used in the policy from your example: The unqualified `name` is interpreted as `owners.name`, so the test always succeeds. To fix the policy, use `locations.name` instead of `name`.
- There is no magic `user_name` variable, and I don't know where you get that from. There is, however, the `current_user` function, which is always available and can of course also be used in a policy definition.
- `WITH CHECK` is a condition that the new row added by `INSERT` or `UPDATE` must fulfill. Since `DELETE` doesn't add any data, `WITH CHECK` doesn't apply to it.

Comment: If it is "*just a `WHERE` clause*", does that mean the table name (and alias?) are available to disambiguate a column name?

Comment: Aliases for the table cannot be used, because they depend on the query. You can qualify the column names with the table name, but I can't think of an example where disambiguation might be necessary.

Comment: See the `owners.name = name` clause in the OP :-)

Comment: Oh, hm, subselects, yes. Anyway, is the case clear now?

Comment: The comment by @bergi has solved my problem. However, as for _how_ policies work, your reply is the correct response, and now I finally understand why there is such limited documentation. Thanks!

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize you had a manifest problem. I have added that to the answer.